# React components does not display items and home breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new with React and I have a React proyect that I am having trouble to make it work. I have a home that display the items, and also I have another component to display the details of the items. Unfortunately, I cannot make them work. Firstly the component ItemList that displays the items in the home breaks all the code. Secondly, the components ItemDetail and ItemDetailContainer that display the details of the items do not show all the items and also do not show the image of it. These are the components:

This is the app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar/NavBar";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Home from "./Components/Home/Home";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ItemDetailContainer from "./Components/ItemDetailContainer/ItemDetailContainer";



const App = () => (  
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path = "/">
          <Home greeting="SAINT TROPEZ RESORT"/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path = "/room/:roomID">
        <ItemDetailContainer />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
    
  );

export default App;
```

This is the home.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ItemList from "../ItemList/ItemList";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


const Home = ({ greeting }) => {
    return(
        <>
            <h1 className="my-3 font-weight-bold text-secondary">Welcome to {greeting}</h1>
            <ItemList />
        </>
)};


export default Home;
```

This is the ItemList.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Item from "../Item/Item";
import Rooms from "../Rooms/Rooms";




const ItemList = () => {
    const datos = new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(Rooms);
    }, 2000)
    );
    
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => datos.then(setList), [datos]);
    
    
    return (
        <Card className='w-50 mt-5 mb-2'>
            <Card.Header as='h3' className='bg-secondary text-light'>
              Our Villas
            </Card.Header>
            {list.map(product => <Item key={product.roomId} room={product} />)}
        </Card>
    );
};    

export default ItemList;
```

This is the ItemDetail.js:

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Card, CardGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Item from "../Item/Item";
import ItemCount from "../ItemCount/ItemCount";


const ItemDetail = (room) => {
    
    return (
        <>            
            <h1 className="my-3 text-secondary">Our Villas</h1>
            <CardGroup>
                <Card className='w-50 mt-5 mb-2'>               
                    <Item room={room} />
                    <ItemCount />
                </Card>
            </CardGroup>        
        </>
     
    );
};

export default ItemDetail;
```

This is the ItemDetailContainer.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useParams } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Rooms from "../Rooms/Rooms";
import ItemDetail from "../ItemDetail/ItemDetail";


const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const datos = (roomID) => {
        return new Promise(result =>  setTimeout(() =>
            { result(Rooms.find(product =>
                product.roomId===parseInt(roomID)))
            },3000))
    }
    
    const {roomID} = useParams();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [room, setRoom] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() =>{
        setLoading(true);
        console.log('loading')
        ItemDetail(roomID).then((product) => {
            setRoom(product);
            setLoading(false)
        });
    }, [datos])    
    
    return (
        <>
           {loading ? <div>loading...</div>
            : <ItemDetail room={room}  />
            }
        </>
    );
        
     
};
  

export default ItemDetailContainer;
```

This is the Item.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardDeck } from "react-bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { NavLink  } from "react-router-dom";


const Item = ({room:{ roomId, roomType, description, img }}) => {

    return (
    <>
      <CardDeck>
        <Card style={{  width: '50' }}>        
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={img} alt="image"/>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title as='h4' className="text-secondary">{roomType}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text ClassName="justify-text-around">
            {description}
          </Card.Text>           
          <NavLink to={`/rooms/${roomId}`}>Click for more details</NavLink>          
        </Card.Body>        
        <Card.Footer className="text-muted">
        SAINT TROPEZ RESORT
        </Card.Footer>    
        </Card>
        </CardDeck>
    </>
    );
    };
    

export default Item;
```

Last this are the items or Rooms.js:

```
const Rooms = [{
        roomId: 1,
        roomType: "One Bedroom Villa",
        description: "This is some description",
        img: "https://i.ibb.co/8ryhgh8/One.jpg",
    },
    {
        roomId: 2,
        roomType: "Two Bedrooms Villa",
        description: "This is some description",
        img: "https://i.ibb.co/BcJFNvs/Two.jpg",
    },
    {
        roomId: 3,
        roomType: "Three Bedrooms Villa",
        description: "This is some description",
        img: "https://i.ibb.co/wNF67X8/Three.jpg",
    }
    ];

    export default Rooms;
```

This is the ItemCount component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';



const ItemCount = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const addMore = () => {
    if (count === 10) {
      console.log(count);
      return;
    }
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  
  const addLess = () => {
    if (count === 0) {
      console.log(count);
      return;
    }
    setCount(count - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonGroup aria-label="Basic example">
        <Button variant="info">Book Online {count}</Button>
        <Button onClick={addLess} variant="outline-info" className="font-weight-bold">-</Button>
        <p className="bg-light px-3 mt-2 text-secondary">  {count}  </p>
        <Button onClick={addMore} variant="outline-info" className="font-weight-bold">+</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>     
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemCount;
```

These are the errors that are in the console:
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see I am using bootstrap for the proyect, but I don't mind if someone can help me with the code without bootstrap. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi, do you have the error code when it breaks? Also, I tried to mimic your app but it is missing the ItemCount component

Comment: Hi @yichiz I put the ItemCount component in the post already. Also, when the page breaks it gets blank the whole page and in console says that: 
The above error occurred in the <ItemList> component:
    in ItemList (at Home.js:10)
    in Home (at App.js:17)
    in Route (at App.js:16)
    in Switch (at App.js:15)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:12)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)

Comment: You don't need to resolve imported classes/files like you are doing currently, that is likely the issue you are facing. Also please post the actual error you get in console. Your comment above provides little helpful information. We need the "The above error"...

Comment: Hi @segFault thanks for the advice. I add to the post images of what the console shows already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer: you do not need a promise and useEffect for getting the Rooms. You can pass the array directly to set the initial state.

### ItemList

```
const ItemList = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(Rooms);

  return (
    <Card className="w-50 mt-5 mb-2">
      <Card.Header as="h3" className="bg-secondary text-light">
        Our Villas
      </Card.Header>
      {list.map((product) => (
        <Item key={product.roomId} room={product} />
      ))}
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

Also, in some component (ex: `Item`) you're spelling `ClassName` instead of `className`. React is case-sensitive.

Hope this help you get started. There are some issues with `ItemDetailContainer` too, but I am not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe you can try without the promise as well.

Comment: Thanks @yichiz do you know how could I show in the component yu gave me only the roomType and the img instead of the whole item??

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios I'm not sure I understand correctly. If you only want the roomType and the img, you have to modify the `Item` component to have only that.